# Convert variable length list into edge list igraph R

Tags: r, list, variables, dataframe, igraph

I have a list in R where each element has a variable number of strings, eg:

```
el: list
chr [1:3] "sales", "environment", "communication"
chr [1:2] "interpersonal", "microsoft office"
chr [1:4] "writing", "reading", "excel", "python"
```

I want to convert this list into a matrix of 2 columns that puts two strings side by side, if they appeared in the same element of the list, e.g.

```
matrix:
"sales", "environment"
"sales, "communication"
"environment", "communication"
"interpersonal", "microsoft office"
"writing", "reading"
"writing", "excel"
"writing", "python"
"reading", "excel"
"reading", "python"
"excel", "python"
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need the output in `matrix`, we can use `combn`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, function(x) t(combn(x, 2))))
#     [,1]            [,2]              
# [1,] "sales"         "environment"     
# [2,] "sales"         "communication"   
# [3,] "environment"   "communication"   
# [4,] "interpersonal" "microsoft office"
# [5,] "writing"       "reading"         
# [6,] "writing"       "excel"           
# [7,] "writing"       "python"          
# [8,] "reading"       "excel"           
# [9,] "reading"       "python"          
#[10,] "excel"         "python"
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned, it might be quicker to call `t` once than multiple times by `unlist`ing the 'lst'

```
matrix(unlist(lapply(lst, combn, 2)), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: Good answer. Might be marginally quicker to `unlist` and feed into a matrix - `matrix(unlist(lapply(el, combn, 2)), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)` - haven't tested that though..

Comment: I have this same problem, but my delimiter is a semicolon (with commas in the text) and the text is in a dataframe value. Maybe I will start another question?

Comment: What is the name of the list? Is it `lst`

Comment: @adm May be you need to split the dataframe column by `,` i.e. `do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$Col), ","),  function(x) t(combn(x, 2))))`

Comment: @akrun This seems to work, but it splits the edge list by comma, when I have semicolons and commas. i.e. "Jones, Bill; Cruz, Tony P; Smith, Sara"

Comment: @adm In that case, you need `"[,;]"`

Comment: @akrun I do not want to separate by the comma, only the semicolon.

Comment: @adm In that case, use the split as `";"`

Comment: @akrun I tried that but I get the error. `Error in combn(x, 2) : n < m`

Comment: @adm Because you may have some elements with a single word or so.  In that case, you need an `if/else` condition ie. `if(length(x) > 2) do this else x`